# Changing schemaLocation in WSDL

Tags: wcf, xsd, wsdl

I have a WCF Service which I need to host on an old IIS 6 server. The server has a name Server1 but also has an alias used for the website. Apparently the server and the website resolve to different IP addresses.

So WCF Service path is

> https://alias.sys.domain.com/ProjectName/MyService.svc?wsdl

But when I look at xml generates, the `schemaLocation` shows up as:

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
     <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://server1.subdomain.domain.com/ProjectName/MyService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" /> 
     <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://server1.subdomain.domain.com/ProjectName/MyService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProjectName" /> 
     <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://server1.subdomain.domain.com/ProjectName/MyService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" /> 
   </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

If I try accessing the schema specified in the xml

> https://server1.subdomain.domain.com/ProjectName/MyService.svc?xsd=xsd0

I get "Page cannot be displayed" error, and if I use Network tab in Chrome debug tools, it shows the call has been aborted. But if I try accessing the schema at

> https://alias.sys.domain.com/ProjectName/MyService.svc?xsd=xsd0

Then I can get to it without a problem but, unfortunately this is not the one used by the service.

To change that I added httpsGetURL in my config file:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="https://alias.sys.domain.com/ProjectName/MyService.svc"  />
```

that caused error:

> A registration already exists for URI

which I was able to get rid of by adding `/mex` after `.svc`. The strange thing is that I do not have `mex` endpoint since I cannot use it due to disabled anonymous authentication.

But adding `/mex` caused another error

> The message with To 'https://alias.sys.domain.com/ProjectName/MyService.svc/mex?wsdl' 
>   cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. 
>   Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.

So then I added address to my endpoint, changing it from

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="Projectname.IMyService"/>
```

to

```
<endpoint address="web1" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="Projectname.IMyService"/>
```

and tried using

> https://alias.sys.domain.com/ProjectName/MyService.svc/web1

that changed my error to

> The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter 
>   mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch 
>   (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between 
>   the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and 
>   the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)
>   [/code]

Can anyone help?

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHTTP">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows">
        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows">
        </transport>
      </security>
   </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="basicBehavior" name="ProjectName.MyService">
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="Projectname.IMyService"/>
    <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="basicBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
          <windowsAuthentication includeWindowsGroups="true" allowAnonymousLogons="false">
         </windowsAuthentication>
    </serviceCredentials>-->
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and here is the interface:

```
public interface IMyService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetStatus/{groupID}/{groupName}", Method = "GET",
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    string GetStatus(string groupID, string groupName);

}
```

Comment: Could you share the service interface and configuration file (endpoint  tag)?

Comment: I added the web.config section and interface. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue by changing

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="basicBehavior" name="ProjectName.MyService">
     <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="Projectname.IMyService"/>

  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="basicBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

to

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="basicBehavior" name="ProjectName.MyService">
     <endpoint address="https://alias.sys.domain.com/ProjectName/MyService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="Projectname.IMyService"/>

  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="basicBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="https://alias.sys.domain.com/ProjectName/MyService.svc/ssl"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot consume a RESTful service operation using WSDL. Even though metadata is exposed over the `?wsdl` query, it's not a valid definition for your service.

WSDL is only for SOAP based operations. You are exposing your operation over pure HTTP.

You should call your service using [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) or [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you need to expose metadata, look at [OpenAPI](https://openapis.org/specification).

Microsoft should remove the metadata functionality for webHttpBinding because it's misleading. That they have not is a signal you should probably abandon WCF for RESTful operations and use [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) or ASP.Net WebAPI.

Comment: should I use different type of binding?  I am just calling it in the browser for testing the xml it produces, it was invalid

Comment: @ElenaDBA If you want to be able to use WSDL to describe your service you should use a SOAP binding like wsHttpBinding. If the consumer application is not also WCF then you should use basicHttpBinding. However, it's actually a lot easier to consume a RESTful service that a SOAP service.

Comment: @ElenaDBA - in fact, I can see in your system.serviceModel config that you have a binding configuration section for basicHttpBinding. I assume there was an endpoint exposed over basic HTTP at some point in the past.

Comment: @TomRedfem, you are exactly right.I changed my binding back to basicHttpBinding but I still have the same issue. Any idea how to fix it?  Apparently the server IP address is different from web site address in this case and that might be causing a problem,

Comment: @ElenaDBA is your problem that you cannot use the ?wsdl address to generate client code from the operation? Can you call the service at all?

Comment: I had the same service hosted on a different server but a newer one - Windows 2012, IIS 8.5, .NET Framework 4.0, and I was able to call the service and add it as service reference. And just open it as wsdl in the browser to see xml. Once i moved the service, i no longer can add it as a service reference.  Now if I cannot use wsdl, I tried `https://alias.sys.domain.com/ProjectName/MyService.svc` and I am getting the error `The registration already exists for URI https://server1.subdomain.domain.com/ProjectName/MyService.svc`